ConstraintLayout Custom view refusing to be used as a contraint
I've created some custom views based on ContraintLayout, which is basically a pairing of a textview and some other component.
EditTextCompat and SwitchCompat.
Both of them are basically created the same way but only the "interactive" part differs.
When I use the CustomEditTextCompat and use it as layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="CustomEditTextCompat" it works as expected.
But when I do the same and try to use the CustomSwitchCompat as a constraint the view just jumps to the top.
Any suggestions?
custom_switch_compat.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:background="@color/black">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/centerLeft_line"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.49" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/centerRight_line"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.51" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
    android:id="@+id/switchTextLabel"
    style="@style/ColorAndFontTheme"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/centerLeft_line"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="Label" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/switchValue"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false"
    android:theme="@style/menuSwitchTheme"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/switchTextLabel"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/centerRight_line"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/switchTextLabel" />
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

CustomSwitchCompat.java
public class CustomSwitchCompat extends ConstraintLayout {
private TextView label;
private SwitchCompat switchCompat;

public CustomSwitchCompat(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context);
    init(context, attrs);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_switch_compat, this, true);
    label = findViewById(R.id.switchTextLabel);
    switchCompat = findViewById(R.id.switchValue);
    TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomSwitchCompat);


    String labelText = attributes.getString(R.styleable.CustomSwitchCompat_switchLabelText);
    label.setText(labelText);
    // Additional attributes such as onText and offText can be set here
    attributes.recycle();
}
}

custom_edit_text_compat.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:background="@color/black">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/centerLeft_line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.49" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/centerRight_line"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.51" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/textLabel"
        style="@style/ColorAndFontTheme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/centerLeft_line"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="Label" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/editInput"
        style="@style/ColorAndFontTheme"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textLabel"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/centerRight_line"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/textLabel"
        tools:text="Editbox" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

CustomEditTextCompat.java
public class CustomEditTextCompat extends ConstraintLayout {
    protected AppCompatEditText editInput;
    private AppCompatTextView textLabel;

    public CustomEditTextCompat(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_edit_text_compat, this, true);

        textLabel = findViewById(R.id.textLabel);
        editInput = findViewById(R.id.editInput);

        TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomEditTextCompat);
        String labelText = attributes.getString(R.styleable.CustomEditTextCompat_labelText);
        String hintText = attributes.getString(R.styleable.CustomEditTextCompat_hintText);

        textLabel.setText(labelText);
        editInput.setHint(hintText);

        attributes.recycle();
    }

    public String getEditTextValue() {
        return editInput.getText().toString();
    }

    public void setLabelText(String text) {
        textLabel.setText(text);
    }

    public void setHintText(String hint) {
        editInput.setHint(hint);
    }
}

Usage:
<com..menuFragments.components.CustomEditTextCompat
        android:id="@+id/custom_attacks_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:hintText="Cool fire wave"
        app:labelText="Attack Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com..menuFragments.components.CustomSwitchCompat
        android:id="@+id/custom_attacks_switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/custom_attacks_name"
        app:switchLabelText="Finish when done" />

    <com..menuFragments.components.CustomEditTextCompat
        android:id="@+id/custom_attacks_box_width"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:hintText="Default"
        app:labelText="Box width"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/custom_attacks_switch" />


In the preview editor I can see that by setting the switch as a constraint the arrow points to the right view and position but it is still pushed to the top of the screen

Use the layout inspector to take a look at the layout in an emulator or an actual device. It will shed some light on what is happening. My guess is that the result of an inflation is not what you expect.

The only strange thing I notice in the layout inspector is that for the CustomSwitchCompat the id is not set, but how could that be possible?
I set it in the code above and use it in several places.
Any ideas or other things I can look at?

Take another look at the Layout Inspector. It looks like you are nesting a ConstraintLayouts within another ConstraintLayout which is not necessary. Consider using a merge tag instead. (You can search for how that is done.) That is probably not the real issues but cleaning up the layout may help. Remember that, in a ConstraintLayout, you can only reference ids that are direct siblings within the same layout.

I'm not sure what to look for, but I do think there is something fishy about the ID.
Testing:
CustomSwitchCompat sc=view.findViewById(R.id.custom_attacks_switch);
CustomEditTextCompat ed=view.findViewById(R.id.custom_attacks_box_width);
Which corresponds with the above ids gives null for the switch but works for my customEditTextCompat

Change super(context)  to super(context,attrs) in CustomSwitchCompat.java. You aren't picking up the id.

omg thank you!
That was the issue, I think I looked and compared the two several times and chatgpt didn't pick up on it either.
Write a real answer and I'll accept it

As you state in a comment: "The only strange thing I notice in the layout inspector is that for the CustomSwitchCompat the id is not set, but how could that be possible?" It is a clue that the id is not set.
The id of the view is picked up from the attributes which must be parsed. This is accomplished in one of the ConstraintLayout constructors, namely, public ConstraintLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs).
In your implementation, you don't actually parse out the id directly but expect to leave that work to the super class of ConstraintLayout as stated above. Unfortunately, you call super(context) and not super(context, attrs), so the id (and all other attributes that would be picked up from the attributes are not picked up at all.
Call through to super(context, attrs) to correct your code.
